# Popup has black background even though it is set to clear

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, popup, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that I'm presenting over another. It should show as a popup with a transparent background. It shows normally, but the background is black. It is presented while embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

The problem is that the background color is black and I can't see the below view, even though all backgrounds colors are set to clear. I even tried setting the backgrounds clear on presenting the controller and still nothing. I have it set in the `Storyboard` to show over current context and cross dissolve.

The view debugger does not show any of the views as black in the hierarchy either. Not sure what is wrong, any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "AccountSettings", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "upgradeVCPopup") as! UpgradeVCPopup
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
nav.view.backgroundColor = .clear
vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
    navigationController.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you have a black background is that you did not set your `UIViewController`s `UIModalPresentationStyle`. This parameter determines how is your modal view controller displayed. The default value for modal view controllers is `fullScreen`.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/fullscreen):

> **UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen**
>
> The views belonging to the presenting view controller are removed after the presentation completes.

This means that after your view controller is presented, the previous view controller is removed. And when it's removed, since there is nothing below it, you see a black color. If you want previous view controller to stay and be visible you may set `modalPresentationStyle` to `overFullScreen`.

From  [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/overfullscreen):

> **UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen**
>
> The views beneath the presented content are not removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation finishes. So if the presented view controller does not fill the screen with opaque content, the underlying content shows through.

To make that, add the following line before presenting your view controller:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

This should help.

Comment: This was it, thanks! I had that correctly set on the VC in the storyboard, and completely didn't realize that I was missing it for the nav, since I was creating that programattically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `nav.view.backgroundColor = .white` By setting the `nav.view.backgroundColor = .clear` you are setting the background of the Navigation window to clear (default base of the Nav window is black)